# Obtaining JSON representation of data rendered in Apache HTTP server HTML files (file structure)

Tags: json, apache, http

I'm running an Apache http server, which currently returns an html page/app that shows the file / folder structure: a few files/folders with videos & pictures I'd like to visualize in a Vue app.

I'd like to obtain the underlying data as JSON rather than having apache generate HTML from it. I'd expect it to contain at least* the five visualized columns, e.g.:

```
        Name                    Last modified     Size  Description
[DIR]   Homemade Media/         2021-05-29 03:03     -   
[   ]   Vide.mp4                2021-05-29 02:33 44440
```

How would I obtain the JSON? Have been unable to find this after quite the search.

*+ anything else that could be available in a potential underlying api(?)

Answer (score 2):

You could enable WebDAV; then you could at least obtain an *XML* representation.